# How do I get data OUT of my asynchronous service return value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some trouble getting the actual data *out* of the return from the api call. I can see the values output into the log, but when I try to access it using **data[0].admin_url** it returns *undefined*.

```
this.apiService
    .getCCUrls()
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data); //output in the image below
        console.log(data[0].admin_url); //returns undefined
    });
```

Which calls this:

```
APIService.prototype.getCCUrls = function() {
    return this.makePublicApiRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/v1/cc-instances',
    });
};
```

There is some simple utility code in between, but eventually it gets to this function...

```
APIService.prototype.makeRequest = function(config) {
    return this.$http(config)
               .then(function(response) {
                   // If we get a replacement token, update it.
                   this.authService.checkResponseHeaders(response);

                   var data = response.data;
                   if (data.data) {
                       return data.data;
                   }
                   if (data) {
                       return data;
                   }
                   return response;
               }.bind(this));
};
```

Lastly, this is what is output in the console.log:

[image]

So, in my first set of code, how do I get to the admin_url, agent_url, or type variables?

Comment: Where is the `data[0].admin_url` call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: @andreas I tried doing console.log(data[0].admin_url); but it just returned undefined. Not sure why.

Comment: Repeating the same things doesn't make them better. Where did you log `data[0].admin_url`? In the last `.then()` (if so, then the image can't be true) or somewhere else?

Comment: @andreas I just edited the post to make it clearer. The image itself is from the very first log. The second console.log is what returns undefined.

Comment: And what about `console.log(data[0]);`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused by the underscore being a `\u0332` underscore:

```js
var x = [{"admin\u0332url":"/cca"}];
console.log(x);
console.log(x[0].admin_url);
console.log(x[0].admin\u0332url);
console.log(Object.keys(x[0]))
```

The Developer Console does not backspace, so a `\u0332` underscore looks the same as an ASCII underscore.

The `x[0].admin_url` would be `undefined` if you try to access it with a string that uses an ASCII underscore.

Answer (score -1):

You need to access data property of the response so, it should be,

```
this.apiService
    .getCCUrls()
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data.data[0].admin_url);
    });
```

Comment: The response (`data`) is an array with one element (object, `[{...}]`). Why should TO use `data.data[0]` when `data` is the array?

Comment: @Andreas i guess OP has posted wrong console , if thats the case it should work when he did data[0].admin_url

Comment: The code given don't contains enough information to support your claim hence this "answer" is just speculation. And if the code doesn't make sense you should probably ask for clarification.

Comment: no clearly if you look at his service you would understand the issue

Comment: The "service" is irrelevant for the problem. The response (`data`) shown is an array of objects and not an object with a `data` property containing an array, hence `data.data[0]` is wrong.

Comment: @sajeetharan the first 'data' is stripped out by the last function. but as I mentioned, when I try data[0].admin_url it is just undefined.

Comment: i dont get it, what is the output you see when you put console.log(data)

Comment: the output is the image at the end of my post above

Comment: oh that is very strange. can you post the json format as comment below? console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: @sajeetharan- the output of the JSON.stringify is this:


[{"agent_url":"/cc/this-other-contact-center","admin_url":"/cca/this-other-contact-center","type":"cc"}]


LOL, I don't understand. Shouldn't either data.admin_url or data[0].admin_url just work then? (before stringify)

Comment: if you are getting that output data[0].admin_url SHOULD DEFINITELY WORK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172313/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-mydoglixu).